Selenium elements going stale on GitHub but not on local when testing
I decided to web scrap the official planning in order to get a better app. (Tried to get an API, but they refuse).
When I test it on my computer, everything works fine and nothing stale, but when I push for the GitHub actions webscrapping it, it stale at the middle. Anyone know what could cause this?
Another thing is that when I want to scrap more (approximately after 15/20 minutes) one element goes stale. How do I prevent this?
Here is the code for scrapping the courses:
if course_id not in output:
        output[course_id] = {}
    output[course_id][name] = {}
    course = course_dict[course_id]
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//table[@class="as-content"]/tbody/tr')))
    driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
    tables = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//table[@class="as-content"]/tbody/tr')
    color = getColor("")
    
    for i in range(1,len(tables),2):
        course_name = tables[i].find_elements(By.XPATH,'./td/table/tbody/tr/td/span')[0].text
        print(course_name)
        if course_name in course:
            course_name, color_ = course[course_name]
            color = getColor(color_)
        if course_name not in output[course_id][name]:
            output[course_id][name][course_name] = []
        list_cursus = tables[i+1].find_elements(By.XPATH,'./td/div/table/tbody/tr')
        for cursus in list_cursus:
            info  = cursus.find_elements(By.XPATH,'./td')
            driver.implicitly_wait(0.1)
            date  = info[0].find_element(By.XPATH,'./div').get_attribute("innerHTML").replace("&nbsp;", " ")
            _time = info[1].get_attribute("innerHTML").replace("&nbsp;", " ")
            row_date = dateparser.parse(date + ' ' + _time[3:8])
            if row_date != None:
                start = row_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
                end   = dateparser.parse(date + ' ' + _time[10:17]).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

                teacher = info[3].get_attribute("innerHTML").replace("&nbsp;", " ")
                room = info[4].get_attribute("innerHTML").replace("&nbsp;", " ")
                title = course_name + '\n' + teacher + '\n' + room

                output[course_id][name][course_name].append({'title':title,'start':start,'end':end, 'color': color})

(EDIT : this code is run multiple times in the main code and maybe it's the modification of the page by running another course that make it stale ?)
I tried to delay more as said on many other forums, but that didn't work. I also tried to change the driver from Chrome to Firefox.
Here is the exception :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/NovaPlanning/NovaPlanning/scraping/scraper.py", line 130, in <module>
    get_information(driver,"BAB1 INFO", "INFO")
  File "/home/runner/work/NovaPlanning/NovaPlanning/scraping/scraper.py", line 101, in get_information
    info  = cursus.find_elements(By.XPATH,'./td')
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 439, in find_elements
    return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENTS, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element with the reference 88f3af23-5a4b-4963-94ce-27c4de81849d is stale; either its node document is not the active document, or it is no longer connected to the DOM; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
StaleElementReferenceError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:725:5
getKnownElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:401:11
deserializeJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:259:20
cloneObject@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:59:24
deserializeJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:289:16
cloneObject@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:59:24
deserializeJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:289:16
json.deserialize@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:293:10
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:73:30


you should include the full exception thrown.

It's done, I'm new on the forum, sorry

sounds like the site redirected.  Try/catch your method calls... when stale element is caught you'll need to re-get the page and re-get all elements.

ok I'll try that as soon as possible

btw, list_cursus will always be a single element (or none at all) so you can switch that to find_element and remove the for loop there.  "./td/div/table/tbody/tr" is a single path.

the site use the  balise to make the list of planned course over the year, I already tried that but it didn't worked.

seems like you'd want "./td/div/table/tbody//tr" if you need find_elements.

I found out by testing some things that by refreshing page between each courses and if stale or others errors already handled, I close driver and open a brand new one. That fix the thing pretty well. (still some stale bet retry to get them in that case)

Stale can also be thrown if you use find_elements while the DOM is still populating... so sleeps before getting find_elements can help in that case... (or catching Stale element exceptions and re-getting element reference arrays when caught)

all works now, thanks for your help :).
